# Bootstrap Popover Plugin not working with dynamic element through ajax

Tags: popover

Using popover of bootstrap Popover Plugin library pulling content from ajax and assigning it to html and then calling  **`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();`** but its not working.

```
$.ajax({
          url : '/recent_activity_jsn.html',
                data : {},
                dataType : 'JSON',
                type : 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success : function(res) {
                   $("#recentActivityDiv").html(recentActivityMaindiv);


                   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 


               },
               error:function(response) {

                 alert("server error please try again");

              }
       });
```